# What are "Content Files" (in Visual Studio : Setup Project : File System

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, installation

In the context of a Visual Studio 2008 Setup Project, what are "Content Files". In other words, when creating a setup project and defining the File System settings and choosing: Add Project Output > Content Files, what files will be added?

For example, what has to be true about a file or its location for it to be considered a Content File for a given project's output?

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The build action property of the file will be labeled "content". Here is a link to more information about [File Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66(v=vs.100).aspx).

[image]

Comment: An additional bit of information... Usually we want to include "Content Files" output group for web applications because .aspx files and graphics are all classed as Content. For other applications, we usually wouldn't include this group.

Comment: Content files are useful even in non-web apps, if wish to have some initial files in your app's content folder, that might be altered or added to by your app. These would be data files (not executables or dlls). In setup, you might specify that they be copied to a subfolder of user's app data. In .Net 4.0+, this might be a folder `\YourCompany\YourApp` within `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`.

Comment: There is no such thing as a content folder. Content is very confusing, it's not clearly defined. Often if you say copy content, you will end up with multiple copies and paths because apparently they are already copied.