# How to enforce Visual Studio to deploy content file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a content file (xml, ***build action = content, copy always***) in a class library (dll).

Many times when the host application (unit test dll, or web app) get recompile due to changes, this content file is not deployed.

it only get to deploy if i explicitly perform a "rebuild" at the host application.

is there a setting a way to ensure the file always get redeploy? already set it to "copy always", but doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this:

1) If you change non-source code files visual studio doesn`t automatically rebuild - they aren't considered when the compiler check occurs.
You may force a complete rebuild by deleting your output directory.

2) In the file properties in Visual Studio, set:

`Build action: None`

`Copy to output directory: Copy always`

Sometimes this helps

Edit: Also consider marking the file as [content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036216/what-are-content-files-in-visual-studio-setup-project-file-system)

Comment: my problem is not due to #1. and the xml file already set as Content, and Copy Always. When host app being auto-rebuild due to some reason, the content can be missed

Comment: ah sorry overread it... you will have to get more information from VS.. please set the "project build output verbosity" setting to Normal. Also enable the option (same page) "On Run, when projects are out of date" setting is set to Always build.. check the output in the console.. does it list any error?